# UML component diagram of dining philosopher problem in client server architecture

Tags: components, uml

I have to describe the structure of the system of dining philosophers using a uml component diagram in a client server architectural style.

I did this:

[image]

but i have many doubts on its correctness:

- is it correct to show every philosopher or should i draw only a generic one? and what about the forks?
- should the forks be included in the table/server component?

Comment: Please update your question to have the actual diagram in the question.  Some of us are not happy going to other sites to try and track down your question so we can answer it.  Also, please enumerate some of the doubts you have.  It's easier for us if you provide your thinking.  Also, since this is homework, please include the [homework] tag.

Comment: thank you, I followed your suggestions. Actually, this is not homework, I'm just trying to exercise before an exam :) But I have put the tag as well.

Comment: I have a question about this topic. Consider the general component diagram, not the instances one: should we draw two sockets (connection) from the philosopher to the dining room / fork interface or is one enough?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you might be trying to show.

- Components in general: Philosopher, Fork, Dining Room.
- Component Instances. Philosopher 0-4, Fork 0-4 and the Dining Room.

The general component diagram doesn't show instances, but shows interfaces, and might include some constraints on the relationships to show that there are 5 instances exactly.

The instance diagram would look similar to what you've shown with 5 instances of the Philosopher component, and 5 instances of the Fork component, and 1 instance of the Dining Room component.

http://argouml-stats.tigris.org/documentation/manual-0.26/ch23s05.html